# Linked List Concatenation

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Working on creating linked lists for an assignment and one requirement is a method named *concat* which takes a list parameter and appends it to the end of the current list. It's not necessary for this method to use recursion, but our programs are supposed to use recursion heavily. I'm just wondering if it's even possible to come up with a recursive algorithm for this. Our list classes only have a head node, nothing else, and they're not doubly linked.

My current attempt can only append the first value recursively. I know what it's doing wrong, but I can't come up with a solution. The first method is what's actually called on a list with a list being passed in to "concatenate". I then attempt to find the tail of the list and pass these in to the recursive method. This "wrapper" method is a mandatory requirement for our recursive methods. Here's my attempt, but it's obviously failing since I'm having trouble advancing the node reference "pt" to the next node in the list once all of the calls pop off the stack and then re-entering recursive calls to *concat*. If this **is** possible with recursion, can you please give me an idea of how to advance this value down the first list and re-enter the recursive calls or maybe just a better general approach towards this problem? Thanks for your time.

```
public void concat(MyString list1) {
    CharacterNode tail = null, pt = list1.head;
    // Find the tail of the list
    if (pt == null) {
    } else if (pt.getNext() == null) {
        tail = pt;
    } else {
        while (pt.getNext() != null) {
            pt = pt.getNext();
        }
        tail = pt;
    }
    list1.head = concat(list1.head, tail, list1.head);
}
private static CharacterNode concat(CharacterNode lhead, CharacterNode tail, CharacterNode pt) {
    // Pass in smaller list every time
    // Head traverses down list till the end
    // Add new node with (pt's letter, null link)
    if (lhead == null) {
    // If head is null, we need to add the node
        lhead = new CharacterNode(pt.getCharacter(),null);
    } else if (tail.getNext() == lhead) {
    // If the head is past tail, stop   
    } else {
        // Call concat on a smaller list
        lhead.setNext(concat(lhead.getNext(),tail,pt));
    }
    return lhead;
}
```

Here's CharacterNode:

```
class CharacterNode {
    private char letter;
    private CharacterNode next;

    public CharacterNode(char ch, CharacterNode link) {
        letter = ch;
        next = link;
    }

    public void setCharacter(char ch) {
        this.letter = ch;
    }

    public char getCharacter() {
        return letter;
    }

    public void setNext(CharacterNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public CharacterNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}
```

MyString:

```
class MyString {
    // member variable pointing to the head of the linked list
    private CharacterNode head;

    // default constructor
    public MyString() {
    }

    // copy constructor
    public MyString(MyString l) {
    }

    // constructor from a String
    public MyString(String s) {
    }

    // for output purposes -- override Object version
    // no spaces between the characters, no line feeds/returns
    public String toString() {
    }

    // create a new node and add it to the head of the list
    public void addHead(char ch) {
    }

    // create a new node and add it to the tail of the list -- "wrapper"
    public void addTail(char ch) {
    }

    // Recursive method for addTail
    private static CharacterNode addTail(CharacterNode L, char letter) {
    }

    // modify the list so it is reversed
    public void reverse() {
    }

    // remove all occurrences of the character from the list -- "wrapper"
    public void removeChar(char ch) {
    }

    // Recursive removeChar method
    private static CharacterNode removeChar(CharacterNode n, char letter) {
    }

    // "wrapper" for recursive length()
    public int length() {
    }

    // Returns the length of the linked list
    private static int length(CharacterNode L) {
    }

    // concatenate a copy of list1 to the end of the list
    public void concat(MyString list1) {
    }

    // recursive method for concat
    private static CharacterNode concat(CharacterNode lhead, CharacterNode tail, CharacterNode pt) {
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't answer this unless we see the definition of MyString and CharacterNode.

Comment: As a side note since recursion is a key concept for your program (and you ask if using recursion is possible for your situation), anything you can do iteratively (with loops), you can also do recursively, and vice versa.

Comment: @Ingo added both of them for you!

Comment: @ajp15243 Thanks, I didn't know you could do anything iterative solutions could do with recursion. That's good to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To concatenate two linked lists, you have to make the last node of first list to point to first node of the second list.

```
Node first_list = ...  // head node
Node second_list = ... // head node
...
Node last_node = first_list.getLastNode()
last_node.setNext(second_list)
```

Now concentrate on implementing `getLastNode()`. It can be done very simply by using either recursion or iteration, literally in 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! That seems to do the trick! :)